# Ubuntu 21.10: Cannot boot any more after last update, ended up in emergency mode

Tags: boot, fstab, acpi

Because of an update I had to reboot. However, my laptop ended up only in emergency mode.
Executing "journalctl -xb" as advised resulted in a ton of messages, some errors from snap. It was not helpful that they are printed in green even when they are not successful.

I finally found the reason for the failure to boot:

Weeks ago, during tests, I had added two lines in /etc/fstab like

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1           ntfs-3g    users,uid=USERNAME,gid=users,locale=de_DE.UTF-8 0 0
```

Which could not be mounted because the device was not present.
When I removed the line the boot worked.

Why has this resulted in such a catastrophic failure?

funnily, if the fstab was corrected but the stick still plugged into the laptop while booting, I got an error `ACPI Bios Error AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT`.

Here [a link to the dmesg output](https://c.gmx.net/@334609157082581438/4Zu_1qmBTBSGBM97N4TPaQ)

Here [a link to the journalctl -xb output](https://c.gmx.net/@334609157082581438/4Zu_1qmBTBSGBM97N4TPaQ)

Here [a link to the dmesg output when fstab was corrected but the stick still plugged into the laptop](https://c.gmx.net/@334609157082581438/6_SFXsnlTEeOP1fQMnMT0Q)

Comment: There's no "Ubuntu 21.20". Is it 21.10 or 22.04? Please [edit] the question to correct it.

Comment: That fstab entry will wait until the drive is present. Check fstab on how to declare a fstab mount for a removable disk. Or look in this [forum](https://askubuntu.com/a/1348879/906933)

Comment: sorry, i corrected the typo, its version 21.20

Comment: "Why has this resulted in such a catastrophic failure?" **If you use `sudo` to edit critical files, you are assuming the risk of destroying your installation if you make a mistake.** That is literally why you have to use sudo and enter your password to edit `fstab`.

Comment: @Organic: but would you not expect the Linux to issue a warning "cannot mount ..." and continue, instead of such an "emergency mode"?

Comment: There is an option in the fstab mounts to do exactly that. I am not sure about the warning, but to continue anyway. Of course it won't be able to continue if the problem is with a critical parition like /

Comment: @Organic: that would be "noauto" or "nofail". But I found the "emergency" state really strange, also Google did not help. I rechecked: if I re-add the fstab line, the error is repeated.